# Remove blank page after TOC and get chapter 1 to start at the numbering of 1

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, page-numbering

I have a problem with the TOC since a blank page is added, with a pagenumber of 1. This means that my book's chapter 1 starts with a pagenumber of 2 on a left page.

The problem occurs, when the TOC is two pages long.

The first page of chapter 1 should start at 1 and on a right page. NB! In the book there is a lot of \pageref which a possible solution should be compatible with.

I would be very pleased if anyone could help me.

See code below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Preface}%

\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Abstract}%
blablablablablablablablablablablablabla

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{chp1}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}

\chapter{chp2}
blablablablablablablablablablablabla

\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}
\section{blablablabla}


\chapter{chp3}
\begin{equation}
2x+2x=4x
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

\chapter{chp4}
blablablablablablablablablablablabla

As stated on page \pageref{eq1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The blank page only occurs because your chapter "chp1"  contains lots of sections without text, so LaTeX can't insert a page break and puts the whole chapter on page 2 instead. Add some text e.g. after section 1.10 and all will be well.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that work in the example I posted, but in my thesis the problem still occurs and i havent any chapters, section, subsection , without any text. So I still have the problem.

Comment: @Frederik Without an example that shows the problem it's hard to say. Make a backup of your thesis and then try to cut segments from it. Make sure that the eventual example still features the problematic blank page.

Comment: @Frederik Note that you may force page breaks in the ToC by adding `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\clearpage}` somewhere in the main text.